# How to get data where Month between two other month in year

Tags: php, laravel

I have table like this :

[image: my_table_1]

In this case, `$dateNow = '2023-10-01';`
How to get data Oktober 2023 from the table above? The result I want is the data that is red color. I am using Laravel 8, PHP 8, and MySQL 8.

The query I mean is something like: `$data = MyModel::whereMonth between start_date and end_date`

Thanks you.

I was try like this:

```
$data = MyModel::whereDate('start_Date', '<=', $dateNow)
     ->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $dateNow);
```

But it return all data before `$dateNow` month.

Comment: You need to add more sample cases for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `whereBetween` method to filter the data based on the `start_date` and `end_date` columns.

```
$dateNow = '2023-10-01';

$data = MyModel::where(function($query) use ($dateNow) {
    $query->whereBetween('start_date', [$dateNow, "{$dateNow} 23:59:59"])
          ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$dateNow, "{$dateNow} 23:59:59"]);
})->get();
```